# sort 3d list var c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a 3D array that contains 3 lists of strings, and I want to sort all the array by the alphabetical order of the first list of strings. is that even possible?

Here is my 3d array:

`var Complete_list = new[] { name_list, Value_list, price_list }.ToList();`

`name_list`,  `Value_list` and `price_list` are just simple  `List<string>`

Can someone help please ?

Comment: You have an array that you initialize with `ToList`? Your question is unclear.

Comment: basically, I have 3 different lists (same size). I want to sort them all simultaneously but the order is defined by the first list

Comment: Your code @Evgeny ???

Comment: The `Complete_list` seems to be useless. It contains only the 3 `List<string>` which you want to sort by the first list. So why you need it at all?

Comment: that is the problem, I searched on the internet but found nothing userfull (maybe i just don't know how to search or what search for), ill try to express more clearfully what i want .

Comment: i have 3 lists `List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
 
  list.Add("a");
        list.Add("b");
        list.Add("d");
        list.Add("c");
  
  
List<string> list2 = new List<string>();
 
  list2.Add("x");
        list2.Add("y");
        list2.Add("z");
        list2.Add("f");
  
  
List<string> list3 = new List<string>();
 
  list2.Add("h");
        list2.Add("f");
        list2.Add("e");
        list2.Add("x");` and i want to sort 1 one alphabetically, and the other ones sort by the same order i sorted the 1 one

Comment: I believe you completely messed up the above variables. You need to be more careful if you expect others to help you. Please read what you write because is seems to have little logical sense.

Also, what does it mean: "sort the arrays in the same order as i sorted the 1st one"? What defines "same order"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to reduce your three lists into a single list that contains an object with three properties. After that you can sort etc.

```
List<string> name_list = new List<string>();
List<string> value_list = new List<string>();
List<string> price_list = new List<string>();

// join the lists into a single list
var combined = Enumerable.Range(0, name_list.Count).Select(i => new
{
    name = name_list[i],
    value = value_list[i],
    price = price_list[i],
});

// here you have a single sorted list that is ordered by 'name'
var sorted = combined.OrderBy(v => v.name).ToList();

// if you need to get them back into separate lists again
var name_list_sorted = sorted.Select(s => s.name).ToList();
var value_list_sorted = sorted.Select(s => s.value).ToList();
var price_list_sorted = sorted.Select(s => s.price).ToList();
```

This code assumes you have the same number of items in each list.

Comment: worked fine thank you